# Android WebChromeClient SSL Url

Tags: java, android, webview, https, webchromeclient

Is there any possibility to load a ssl url in a WebView with WebChromeClient? I need WCC for an image chooser because this doesnt work in normal WebViewClient but I could not get the SSL working in WebChromeClient.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Likely a dupe. I can't find it, though.